# Как удалить элемент на странице?

Tags: javascript

Как удалить элемент на странице?

Comment: http://learn.javascript.ru/modifying-document#удаление-узлов-removechild

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function remove(id)
{
    return (elem=document.getElementById(id)).parentNode.removeChild(elem);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.