# Как удалить html код ? jquery

Tags: jquery

Есть вот код

```
$('input[name="city[]"]').click(function() {
    var checked = $('input[name="city[]"]').is(':checked');
    if(checked === true){
        $.post("site/cityzone?id="+$(this).val(), function( data ) {
            $("#city_list").append(data);
        });
    }
    else {
        $.post("site/cityzone?id="+$(this).val(), function( data ) {
            $("#city_list").remove(data);
        });
    }
});
```

В переменной `data` примерно следующее

```
<li class="custom-checkbox">
    <input type='checkbox' name='city_zone[]' value='19' id='city_zoneКотовского поселок'>
    <label for='city_zoneКотовского поселок'>Котовского поселок</label>
</li>
<li class="custom-checkbox">
    <input type='checkbox' name='city_zone[]' value='20' id='city_zoneЛузановка'>
    <label for='city_zoneЛузановка'>Лузановка</label>
</li>
<li class="custom-checkbox">
    <input type='checkbox' name='city_zone[]' value='21' id='city_zoneПересыпь'>
    <label for='city_zoneПересыпь'>Пересыпь</label>
</li>
```

По нажатию на чекбокс идет post запрос на сервер, который возвращает html код. Он находится в переменной data. Стоит задача, если клик на чекбокс `.is(':checked')` - тогда нужно добавить html код которые возвращает сервер - `$("#city_list").append(data);` , в другом случае нужно удалить этот код, который мы вставили. Каким образом это можно реализовать ?? Нужно ли опять слать запрос на сервер, чтобы узнать что удалять или нет?

Пробовал аналогичным методом, только `$("#city_list").remove(data);` - не получается, ошибки.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как удалить элемент на странице?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/207801/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5)

Comment: для того, чтобы очистить элемент `city_list` - можно использовать метод [`.empty`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/)

Comment: Тут вопрос в том, прилетают ли в `data` все содержимое `city_list` или только его часть. Варианта два: парсить прилетевший html, вытаскивать селекторы, по этим селекторам удалять код на странице (неоптимальный метод) или изменить формат ответа, чтобы он возвращал только селекторы удаляемых элементов.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что у вас несколько чекбоксов (городов) и вы хотите для отмеченных городов вывести общим списком их районы (зоны)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`remove` используется так:

```
$("#id элемента,который надо удалить").remove();
```

Те вам надо по *id* найти элементы , которые надо удалить. Например, так:

```js
 data = "<li class='custom-checkbox'>\
    <input type='checkbox' name='city_zone[]' value='20' id='city_zoneЛузановка'>\
    <label for='city_zoneЛузановка'>Лузановка</label>\
  </li>\
  <li class='custom-checkbox'>\
    <input type='checkbox' name='city_zone[]' value='21' id='city_zoneПересыпь'>\
    <label for='city_zoneПересыпь'>Пересыпь</label>\
  </li>";


 $('input[name="city"]').click(function() {
   var checked = $('input[name="city"]').is(':checked');
   if (checked === true) {
     //закоментировано для теста
     // $.post("site/cityzone?id=" + $(this).val(), function(data) {
     $("#city_list").append(data);
     // });
   } else {
     // $.post("site/cityzone?id=" + $(this).val(), function(data) {
     $data = $(data)
     //находим инпуты с id-шниками
     $data.find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
       //находим инпуты для удаления и удаляем вместе с родительским li
       $("#city_list #" + $(this).attr('id')).parent().remove()
     })

     // });
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type=checkbox checked name="city">city</label>
<ul id=city_list>
  <li class="custom-checkbox">
    <input type='checkbox' name='city_zone[]' value='19' id='city_zoneКотовского поселок'>
    <label for='city_zoneКотовского поселок'>Котовского поселок</label>
  </li>
  <li class="custom-checkbox">
    <input type='checkbox' name='city_zone[]' value='20' id='city_zoneЛузановка'>
    <label for='city_zoneЛузановка'>Лузановка</label>
  </li>
  <li class="custom-checkbox">
    <input type='checkbox' name='city_zone[]' value='21' id='city_zoneПересыпь'>
    <label for='city_zoneПересыпь'>Пересыпь</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```